# Pass JSON value from PHP to Angular through URL

Tags: php, angular, angular-ui-router, angular6, angular-router

I'm having trouble sending JSON object back to Angular application from PHP script. I tried to do it by URL but I am unable to send JSON:

```
header("Location: http://localhost:8000/index.html#/AnotherPage/abcd");
```

**Here is my PHP code**

```
<?php
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

// following files need to be included
require_once("./lib/config_paytm.php");
require_once("./lib/encdec_paytm.php");

$paytmChecksum = "";
$parameterList1;
$paramList = array();
$isValidChecksum = "FALSE";

$parameterList1 = $_POST;
$paramList = $_POST;

$paytmChecksum = isset($_POST["CHECKSUMHASH"]) ? $_POST["CHECKSUMHASH"] : ""; //Sent by Paytm pg

//Verify all parameters received from Paytm pg to your application. Like MID received from paytm pg is same as your application’s MID, TXN_AMOUNT and ORDER_ID are same as what was sent by you to Paytm PG for initiating transaction etc.
$isValidChecksum = verifychecksum_e($paramList, PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY, $paytmChecksum); //will return TRUE or FALSE string.


if($isValidChecksum == "TRUE") {
    echo "<b>Checksum matched and following are the transaction details:</b>" . "<br/>";
    if ($_POST["STATUS"] == "TXN_SUCCESS") {
        echo "<b>Transaction status is success</b>" . "<br/>";
        print_r($paramList);
        echo $paramList;
        //Process your transaction here as success transaction.
        //Verify amount & order id received from Payment gateway with your application's order id and amount.
    }
    else {
        echo "<b>Transaction status is failure</b>" . "<br/>";
    }

    if (isset($_POST) && count($_POST)>0 )
    { 
        foreach($_POST as $paramName => $paramValue) {
                echo "<br/>" . $paramName . " = " . $paramValue;
        }
        print_r($paramList);
    }


}
else {
    echo "<b>Checksum mismatched.</b>";
    //Process transaction as suspicious.
}
header("Location: http://localhost:8000/index.html#/AnotherPage/abcd");
?>
```

here is my Angular project typescript code , which will receive json data sent by php ,

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'page-another',
  templateUrl: 'another.html',
})
export class AnotherPage {

  userData:any;
  id:any;''

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

    this.userData = navParams.get('data');
    // this.id = navParams.get('id');

    console.log(navParams.get('id'));
    console.log(this.userData);
  }

}
```

Comment: Sending JSON data via URL is never recommended approach, Why not to store data itno Localstorage? Or either call get HTTP request from server to get data again there?

Comment: you need to use AJAX on your angular page to get a response from PHP. first client will request the server ajax will send the request for data to PHP and then PHP will process the code and sendback the response.

Comment: if you want to send data from php to angular page then you need to use server sent events.